# Discourse redirect url's

Tags: ruby, redirect, discourse

I've imported my forum Mybb to Discourse. Discourse forum live now. But i've problem with redirect old urls to news.

old forum url: `http://sub.site.com/thread-the-title-of-the-post.html`

new forum url: `http://sub.site.com/the-title-of-the-post/`

How i can redirect all urls in a mass?

Comment: There are many ways this could be done.

Comment: I need some examples and i need eaiest way :) Discourse has own permalinks redirects system but it is not useful for all urls in one.